# Trouble with instantiating templated class

Tags: c++, constants

OK updating the question since the error messages have changed.

My driver file has the main function to test the code and is set up such as:

```
  int main(){
  mutable_heap<int> mutaheap;
  return 0;
  }
```

My default constructor for mutable_heap is:
    mutable_heap(){}

The error for this I get is 'see reference to class template instantiation 'mutable_heap' being compiled'

Comment: `const T& new` this can't possibly compile.

Comment: dont use reserved keywords mate: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword

Comment: What "troubles" are you having exactly?

Comment: changed it from reserved keyword, that wasn't the issue I have it named differently in my program. My trouble is learning to find a way to change the old_val to the new_val in my unordered_map.

Comment: What exactly is your problem with that? Where's your code and how is it failing? What would you do if the references weren't `const&` and why can't you do that with what you have?

Comment: Have you tried something like `it->second = new_val;` to modify what's in the map? (We're just guessing what you need since you haven't show what you've tried.)

Comment: updated with my fuller code. I am getting 'left of ->second errors'

Comment: @JohnD so what's not working with that (edited) code?

Comment: 'left of ->second must point to class/union/struct

Comment: Add the **exact** error message to your post.

Comment: In fact, `"mutable_heap.h"` is what we want.

Comment: This post should be closed, as the question is still incomplete and not reproducible. The post is misleading as `map` in the OP is (implicitly) assumed by everybody to be a `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`, but apparently is not. Furthermore, it seems that the OP does not provide all the error messages.

Comment: I've clarified in the code the errors I am getting for the particulars.

Comment: @JohnD You did not clarify anything. `'see reference to class template instantiation 'mutable_heap' being compiled'` is not an error itself. It shows in Visual Studio output to tell you where instantiation of a template (that caused **actual error**, that you didn't post) has been requested. If you want help, post code of `mutable_heap`, because error is probably there. Otherwise, it is impossible to answer your question, so it will be most likely closed.

Comment: The amount of information currently in this question is like going to the doctor, saying "something hurts", and expecting to get a remedy.

Comment: I'm inclined to undo recent edits. The OP should not be allowed to arbitrarily change the question. If the problem has changed, ask a *new* question.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the spec](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/find/), key is always received as const reference:

```
iterator find ( const key_type& k );
const_iterator find ( const key_type& k ) const;
```

No surprise here. But as along as your map is mutable (i.e. non-const qualified), you receive `iterator` as a result, which is a modifiable wrapper, that holds particular value stored inside container.

So, basically:

```
void update(const T& old_val, const T& new_val)
{
    auto it = map.find(old_val);
    if(it != map.end)
    {
        //unordered_map stores std::pair<hash, value>
        it->second = new_val;
    }
}
```

I assume, that `update` is either global function or non-static member function. In first case there should be no problems, in second - I don't see `const` qualifier, so there should not be any problem either.

Is this the solution you have tried?

Comment: Yes this is what I am trying, I added the error messages to the post. Thanks for the input everyone.

Comment: @JohnD I see. It's not enough, problem lies elsewhere. I would gladly see your `#include` directives and definition of `mutable_heap`.

Comment: I believe I am having trouble with the mutable_heap defintion. I will add the definition to my post.